# D3.js: Context + Focus zoom on multiple graphs

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I was looking into the following example by Mike Bostock on focus + context zooming. https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367.

I was wondering if we can link multiple charts with a main graph. Something similar to the attached image. I am quiet new to d3.js so i might have missed something but i am unable to find any links on how to go about it. All of the graphs have equal data points.

Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends obviously on how your data is organized. I imagine you have a `data` array as follows:

```
[ {date : ...  /*x-coordinate*/
   price1 : .../*first y-coordinate*/
   price2 : .../*second y-coordinate*/  
               /* ...and as many as you like*/
  },
  {date : ...
   price1 : ...
   price2 : ... } 
]
```

You also have an array containing the names of the fields you want to fetch as y-axis:

```
fields = ["price1", "price2", ...]
```

So first thing to do is a way to extract the data for each separate curve. This can be done as follows:

```
function singleCurveData(fieldId) {
   return data.map(function (d) { 
      return {date: d.date, price: d[fieldId]};
    });
}
```

If your data is organized differently, only this function needs to change. Basically, it receives the id of the graph you want to draw, and outputs the data for this specific graph in a standard fashion.

---

Now to the drawing section. You need as many `focus` parts as different fields you want to show, each one containing a single `area`; and a single `context` part containing many `area2`s.

```
var focus = svg.selectAll(".focus")
  .data(fields) //associate one field id to each focus block
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "focus")
  .attr("transform", function(d,i) {return "translate(" + margin.left + "," + (margin.top - i*focusHeight) + ")"});
    //the above line takes care of the positioning, you need to know the target height of a focus block.

var context= ...//as before
```

And now we move on to drawing the curves:

```
focus.append("path") //append one path per focus element
  .datum(function(fieldId) {return singleCurveData(fieldId)}) //only this line changes
  .attr("class", "area")
  .attr("d", area);


context.selectAll("path")
  .data(fields) // add a "path" for each field
  .enter()     
  .append("path") //here the datum for the path is the field Id
  .datum(function(fieldId) {return singleCurveData(fieldId)})
                  //now the datum is the path data for the corresponding field
  .attr("class", "area")
  .attr("d", area2);
```

This should be all there is to it. Good luck!